# Project Online - access project data and custom list in C# application

Tags: sharepoint-online, ms-project, officedev, project-online

I've been asked to pull some data from our MS Project online instance.  I have worked out how to register an app and i've been able to connect to get some data with

```
Web web = context.Web;
          context.Load(web.Lists,
          lists => lists.Include(list => list.Title, list => list.Id));
```

That basically returns a list of items but there is 2 things that I am then lost off how to achieve:

1. Access a list of projects
2. Access to a custom project specific list, the example url that is located at is xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/DSP/{Project Name}/Lists/PMUpdates/AllItems.aspx

I'm also not completely understanding where Project Online ends and Sharepoint starts. Is what I am trying to achieve technically Project Online integration or Sharepoint integration?